# What is this Tom Pam Britanny in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

What is this in Google slides page? I tried checking the meaning of Tom, Pam, etc using Google but the meanings could not be understood, is it idiomatic?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

When using Google Docs, Sheets and Slides to edit documents, several people can edit at once. You can see the cursors of other users as a coloured cursor (or, in sheets, a coloured box around the selected cell) with that user's name attached to it - just as shown in the animation.

This is showing how the hypothetical Tom, Pam and Brittany can all edit at once. That is all. It's just names of people.